# How To Remove Individual Office 2016 for OS X Applications

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have Office 2016 installed - Excel, Outlook, Power Point and Word.
I want to remove Outlook 2016 and leave the rest.
I want to leave no trace behind, a complete remove of Outlook as if I installed only the other 3.

How can I do that?
What if I want to remove a different one?

Thank You.

Comment: Anyone? Please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) and selected every Microsoft Product and then `Select` to be finished with `Delete`.